# Install Wordpress / Red Hat 9

Tags: linux, wordpress, installation, redhat

I trying to install WordPress on Redhat 9, but the server don't running PHP and return
the default Apache welcome page [Default Apache Welcome Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krPQD.png)

Any clue?

Comment: Maybe you should post it on [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com/) to get better response, also improve your question, it's not enough to understand anything from this question.

Comment: Seems obvious that the first thing to do is to install PHP in the server. It's impossible to run WP without PHP, hence the default Apache welcome page.

Answer (score 0):

From the lack of detail in the post, I can only guess that the Apache Welcome page is showing up as you have not edited the `welcome.conf`.

```
/etc/httpd/conf.d/welcome.conf
```

And if the host is hosing multiple domains then you need to add a .conf for each domain to redirect the domain to the specific path on the server. Check out more details and some examples [here](http://www.techiecorner.com/1822/how-to-remove-apache-test-page-in-centos/).

Regarding the Wordpress installation and that the server doesn´t run PHP... we need more details. If there is no PHP support on the server then you can read more about it here: How to [Install WordPress on CentOS 5 in five minutes flat](http://blog.adlibre.org/2010/03/10/how-to-install-wordpress-on-centos-5-in-five-minutes-flat/).